# How many unique combinations to wear seven different socks?

Tags: combinatorics

My friend has seven unique but similar socks.

How many ways does he have to wear them, not double counting same combos?

$\mathbf {Attempt}$

I think $7! - 5!$ , but then you forget you can put the first foot sock on the other foot as well so $7!-5!+6$ is the correct answer?

Comment: What is the $-5!$ for? The answer must be more than $7!$ because there are $7!$ ways to wear all $7$ socks on his left foot, and then another $7!$ ways to wear them all on his left foot, and lots more ways to split them between his two feet. (I assume we don't consider wearing them on his hands or his head. What about turning a sock inside out, does that count as a different way?)

Comment: @bof How can there be $7!$ ways to wear a single sock on the left foot? There are $7$ ways to wear a sock on the left foot.

Comment: Does your friend ever wear more than one sock on the same foot at once? (It's cold these days.) Does he sometimes wear them inside out, and does that matter when counting? I guess socks are not so big that he can fit both feet in the same sock?!

Comment: Huh.  There are seven socks he can put on his left foot and six remaining socks he can put on his right foot.  So 42.  Unless the question says otherwise I refuse to contemplate wearing multiple socks on a foot or going or putting two feet in a sock or putting a sock on your tongue or....

Comment: @StellaBiderman The question asks "How many ways does he have to were them", the pronout *them* evidently referring to the seven socks. Given that the man has to wear seven socks, he is probably going to put more than one sock on one foot.

Comment: To conclude he must wear all 7 from "how many ways are there to wear then" is a stretch.  At best, this question is vague.  I say the answer is 3. He can wear them i) at home, ii) at work and iii) for formal occassions.  Three ways.

Comment: @fleablood It's clearer from the title: "How many unique combinations ***to wear seven different socks?***. If you have just one sock on each foot, you are (probably) not wearing seven different socks.

Comment: Well, does it count if a wear them inside out?  What body part I put them on? Is putting them on at 7 am while eating breakfast count differently than if I put them on a 3 am in a sexual escapade? And in what ontological sense is "I chose to not wear it" not count as a way to wear something?  I think it is far too vague.

Comment: Given the obvious disagreement in the comments about what counts and what doesn’t count as an answer, I’m nominating that we close this question as unclear until the OP specifies what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

You are choosing $2$ socks from $7$ socks. That is ${7\choose 2}=\frac{7!}{2!5!}=21$, where you can first choose from $7$ socks, then you can choose from the $6$ remaining socks (so $7\cdot 6=\frac{7!}{5!}$) and due to counting each pair double, you divide by $2!=2$.

I think it's pretty well explained here, also for the general case $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$:
https://betterexplained.com/articles/easy-permutations-and-combinations/

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If he puts $n $ on the left foot, $m $ on the right foot and leaks $k $ off, there are $$\sum_{n=0}^7 7Pn (\sum_{m=0}^{7-n}7-n Pm)= \sum_{n=0}^7 \frac {7!}{(7-n)!} (\sum_{m=0}^{7-n}\frac {(7-n)!}{(7-n-m)!})= 7!\sum_{n=0}^7  (\sum_{m=0}^{7-n}\frac 1 {(7-n-m)!} )$$ ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

7! ways to wear different sock

Answer (score -1):

You have $7$ choices for your left root. Then you have $6$ choices for the right. This gives $42$ choices. However, this counts $AB$ and $BA$ as different, while the problem says to not double count the same pair. So we have half that many choices, so $21$ is the answer.

Comment: But then you forget again the scenario that you can place all 7 socks starting on *either* foot. Must be more?

Comment: And e.g. red sock left green right IS separate from green left red right

Comment: Where is Toni getting that you can place all seven socks on either foot?  The criteria of what a "combo" or what a same combo is makes this question too vague to answer.  With no other condition I think stella's answer of 42 (not 21; there is no good reason to consider AB as the same as BA) is clearly the most reasonable one.

Comment: @fleablood What do you take “not double counting same combos” to mean, if it doesn’t mean that $AB$ and $BA$ are the same?

Comment: @Toni The same question to you.

Comment: I'I'm taking the question as too vague and poorly worded to be answerable.  "Same combo" is given *absolutely* no context to any meaning and I don't take to be possibly interpreted correctly.

Comment: If the socks are all different, imo, "same combos" simply are not possible.  Unless there is some stipulation as to what a same combo is.  Left and right irrelevant is one way.  Putting a green sock over a red sock being the same as the other order.  But what I think the op actually means is:  there are $7!*3^7$ ways to place seven socks on either the left, right or neither foot.  But this double counts pointing the blue sock 1st on the left and red 2nd on right as same as red on right 1st blue on left 2nd.  If so this is the ring problem.